# How do you downgrade from React 18 to React 17?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to downgrade to React 17 after using create-react-app to create a react application.  I uninstalled react and react-dom version 18 from the package.json file and installed version 17 of these modules.  When I run "npm start", I get the error "**Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client'**" in the terminal.  I also deleted the package-lock.json and preformed a npm install to see if that would help but no joy.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

1. `npm install react@17.0.0 react-dom@17.0.0`
2. change testing libraries to

   `@testing-library/react": "^12.0.4`,
   `@testing-library/user-event": "^12.0.9`
3. Change index.js to

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import { render } from "react-dom";
   import "./index.css";
   import App from "./App";
   const root = document.getElementById("root");
       render(<App />, root);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

After some searching on ReactDOM, it states on the React website that ReactDOM.render has been replaced with [ReactDOM.createRoot](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html). Since React 18 is using ReactDOM.createRoot, I had to change the code in the index.js file from

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

to

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

After these code changes, I was able to run version 17 of React.